# Grouping xml attributes in an object with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, data-binding, jaxb

I would like to group attributes of a xml element in a nested object. 
I have this two objects:

**CttXml.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ctt")
public class CttXml {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private EmtXml emtXml;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "a")
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "b")
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public EmtXml getEmtXml() {
        return emtXml;
    }

    public void setEmtXml(EmtXml emtXml) {
        this.emtXml = emtXml;
    }
}
```

**EmtXml.java**

```
public class EmtXml {
    private String c;
    private String d;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "c")
    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.class = c;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "d")
    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

The real EmtXml class has a lot more attributes that I have ommited for simplicity, and `emtXml` can be null in the CttXml object

The target xml I would like to achive is the following:

```
<ctt a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4" />
```

But instead I'm having an `emtXml` element inside `ctt`:

```
<ctt a="1" b="2">
    <emtXml c="3" d="4" />
</ctt>
```

I feel that I'm missing some kind of annotation on the EmtXml object of CttXml class.

Comment: As far as I know, this is just how JAXB works, it sees an embedded element with attributes and with that serializing it in the result you gave. The only way I could see this working is if you were to make your own Serializer/Deserializer, as JAXB would never implement it in the way you desire.

Comment: You don't really need your own serializer / deserializer; you can do this with an adapter as well. More info: [XmlAdapter - JAXB's Secret Weapon](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html)